# phpunit + symfony The Error Handler has Changed

Tags: php, phpunit, symfony

I wrote some PHP Unit Tests, that need User Authentication for a Request. 
For that i added some parameterse to createClient:

```
$this->client = static::createClient(array(), array(
    'PHP_AUTH_USER' => TEST_USER_NAME,
    'PHP_AUTH_PW' => TEST_USER_PASS,
));
```

`TEST_USER_NAME` and `TEST_USER_PASS` containing the Login Credentials. 
If I do a request like that

```
$parameters = array(
    "object" => self::TEST_OBJECT_ID,
);

$headers = array(
    'HTTP_API_AUTHORIZATION' => 'API_AUTH_KEY',
);

$this->client->request('POST', '/api/v4/object/get', $parameters, array(), $headers);
$response = $this->client->getResponse();
$this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode(), $response->getContent());
```

The test says OK, but after that this Message appears:

> THE ERROR HANDLER HAS CHANGED!

If i change the Credentials to something wrong, the message does not appear. 
Any suggestions how i can prevent that or remove this message?

Comment: Run phpunit --self-update

Comment: $ bin/phpunit --self-update
$ unrecognized option --self-update

Comment: Hmm... Symfony probably wants to see PHPUnit 5.1.3+ . That's weird that it' doesn't recognize the --self-update

Comment: i installed phpunit via composer in the project itself. just updated to 5.3 and same result.

Comment: The PHAR of PHPUnit releases prior to PHPUnit contain an SSL certificate that does not match the one in use on phar.phpunit.de today.

This is not a bug. It cannot be fixed. The best way to deal with the issue at hand would be to either download https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar directly instead of using phpunit --self-update or, even better, put the phpunit.phar in your project's sourcecode repository.

Comment: @MohamedBenHENDA isn´t it that what i currently have, if i include it via composer into my project?

Comment: @deveth: With composer is the correct way.

Comment: @MohamedBenHENDA thanks. i found my mistake. see the answer on the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my mistake - i browsed all tests and regarding code and it was was the error said, i changed the error handler.

```
set_error_handler(array(&$this, 'handleGeoError'));
```